# Counting the steps of an algorithm for an upper bound

Tags: runtime, big-o, time-complexity

I know that If I have a for loop, and a nested for loop, which both iterate `1 to n` times, I can multiply the run times of both loops to get `O(n^2)`. This is a clean and simple calculation. However, if you had iterations like so,

`n = 2, k = 5`

`n = 3, k = 9`

`n = 4, k = 14`

where `k` is the number of times the inner for loop iterates. At one point, it is larger than `n^2`, then it is exactly `n^2`, then it becomes less than `n^2`. Assuming you cannot determine `k` based on `n`, and maybe even having these points of `n` very far apart how do you calculate Big-O?

I tried graphing points. And at one point, I could say it was `O(n^3)` since some points exceed `n^2`, and further down, it would be `O(n^2)`. Which one should I choose?

Comment: Can you give us an example code? If you want to express the complexity in terms of `n`, you have to find a bound for `k` in terms of `n`.

Comment: An algorithm I had in mind was one where the total number of iterations `k`, for any array of size `n` was undeterminable mathematically. Basically, without a pattern. I picked random values for `n` and `k` in my original question, which I hope has no pattern. An algorithm like this is possible isn't it? It's not a question that I came across, rather one that popped into my head while learning to calculate runtime by adding steps.

Comment: If you choose `k` randomly, you have to use the maximal possible value of `k` to calculate the complexity. If `n` and `k` not related in any way, the complexity will be a function in terms of `n` and `k`. But this seems to be a very artificial algorithm. In general you can use characteristics of the problem the algorithm solves to find relations or upper bounds of your parameters. And note that calculating the complexity of an algorithm can be very hard and sometimes it is not possible (so you get only a very bad upper bound)

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state in your question that `k` is:

> *"... At one point, it is larger than `n^2`"*

This is the uncertainty (or non-specificity) in your question that makes it hard to answer rigorously. Anyway, for the remainder of this answer, we shall assume that what you mean by the quote above is that:

> For all values of `n`, the value of `k(n)` is bounded from above by
>   `C·n^2`, for some constant `C>0`.

From here on, let's refer to this statement as `(+)`.

---

Now, since you're mentioning Big-O notation, we'll proceed to somewhat loosely define what this actually means:

> `f(n) = O(g(n))` means `c · g(n)` is an **upper bound** on `f(n)`. Thus 
>   there exists some constant `c` such that `f(n)` is always `≤ c · g(n)`, 
>   **for sufficiently large `n`** (i.e. , `n ≥ n0` for some constant `n0`).

I.e., Big-O notation is a way to describe an upper bound here for the *asymptotic* (limiting) behaviour of our algorithm. You write in your question, however, that:

> *"And at one point, I could say it was `O(n^3)` since some points exceed `n^2`, and further down, it would be `O(n^2)`"*

Now this is a very specific analysis of how the inner loop of your algorithm behaves for specific values of `n`, and really not something that is related to asymptotic analysis (or Big-O notation). We're not interested in specifics about how the algorithms behaves for specific values of `n`, but whether we can find some general upper bound for the algorithm given `n` is "sufficiently large" (n ≥ n0 for some constant `n0`).

Now, with these comments above, we can proceed to analysing the asymptotic behaviour of your algorithm.

---

We can approach this using Sigma notation, making use of statement `(+)` above, `k(n) < C·n`:

[image]

The last step `(++)` follows from the definition of Big-O-notation, that we loosely stated above.

Hence, given that we interpret your information regarding `k` as `(+)`, your algorithm runs in `O(n^3)` (which is an *upper* bound, not necessarily a tight one).

Comment: For `k` being larger than `n^2`, I meant that it passes `n^2` as an upper bound. For example, when `n = 2, k = 5`. However, I don't understand why you are bounding the inner for loop to `n^2`. Would that not make a simple nested for loop algorithm, with both outer and inner being `1...n` also be `O(n^3)`?

Comment: @fossdeep I'll quote the comment from AbcAeffchen from above: _"If you want to express the complexity in terms of `n`, you have to find a bound for k **in terms of** n"_. All you've given us is that `k` _"at one point is larger than n^2"_; we can't really use this, but the answer above shows Big-O asymptotic analysis of the algorithm given that we can express `k`(for _all_ values of `n`) as bounded from above by `C · n`, for some constant `C>0`. Note also that in the Sigma-notation above, we don't "make the loop a simple nested loop", we derive a bound for your algorithm, using a bound on `k`.

Comment: @fossdeep ... I suggest you update your question with more details regarding how `k` relates to `n`.